# How to minimize the number of values that are not 0?

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, pytorch, loss-function

If my output is a tensor of values:

```
torch.tensor([0.0, 1.2, 0.1, 0.01, 2.3, 99.2, -21.2])
```

I'm trying to create a differentiable loss function that will minimize the number of values that are not 0. That is, the actual values don't matter, I just need to have less values that are not 0.

How can I get the needed loss value?

So far I tried L1 loss (taking the mean absolute value of this tensor), but this just minimize the values and not necessarily make more 0s. So for example, the results of the L1 loss can be `torch.tensor([0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1])`. However, this should be worse than `torch.tensor([120.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])` which is not the case.

**Update:**
I came up with a loss function that will capture some of what I needed, but it's not perfect. In particular, the gradient will be 0 (and hence won't propagate) when the values are far away from 0.

The loss is `torch.tanh(torch.abs(torch.tensor([0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]))*1e3).mean()`. The idea is to make the value positive with the `abs`, then large with some constant value `1e3`, then the `tanh` will make each `1`. This should ignore the value of the numbers and just focus on how many zeros. But like I said, this is really not optimal as the gradient will be 0 (and hence won't propagate) when the values are far away from 0. So I'll keep this question open as this is only a temporary, not great solution (but maybe help generate ideas for a different one)

Comment: How about taking the element-wise squared log of your tensor? `torch.mean(torch.log(t**2))`. This won't give you exactly zero but close enough? Maybe taking `log10` would be "softer" since this would grow to -inf.

Comment: @OmarAlSuwaidi I think the issue with that will be that if I have values that are smaller than 1 (e.g 0.1 like in the example), the loss will be negative. So again I think this might minimize the values rather than "focus" on the zeros

Comment: Yeah but that doesn't affect the optimization process. You're still minimizing the loss as you're getting closer and closer to zero value entries (desired behavior). The loss being negative doesn't actually change anything in terms of the optimization process (think of minimizing `(pred - target)**2 - 10` for example).

Comment: What you're talking about is a sparsity inducing loss function. There is a ton of work in the area of sparseness and sparsity inducing losses. The most common method is to use an L1 penalty. Despite your example, there are reason why this loss enforces sparsity, I'm sure you can find more information online with the proper search terms. Ideally you would have an L0 penalty, but this is, as you point out, non-differentiable and ends up requiring a combinatorial optimization. L1 penalty is the tightest convex relation of L0 which is one way to think about why it induce sparsity

Comment: In my opinion a better, more visual example is to consider the L1 norm ball in R2 with a linear objective function. If the goal is to find the minimum loss subject to a fixed L1 loss then it's possible to intuitively and visually see why a minimum is always on either the x or y axis. This is explained more thoroughly [here](https://blog.mlreview.com/l1-norm-regularization-and-sparsity-explained-for-dummies-5b0e4be3938a).

Comment: @jodag Thanks a lot for the explanation and the link, it was really helpful. I'll keep reading about it and see if I find something slightly in between L0 and L1 (maybe L_1/2? : ) ). Mostly because in my training it doesn't seem like L1 is sufficient. I came up with a loss function but it's really not perfect, but maybe slightly better than L1 in this case. So I'll keep this question open (see my update).